# Subdomain virtualmin is not working

Tags: linux, virtualhost, ubuntu, webmin

Hello there and thank you for your time.

I have a domain working very well on Linux Server with Virtualmin which is `vuelosenglobos.mx`.

Within `vuelosenglobos.mx` domain i've created `erp.vuelosenglobos.mx` as "subdomain" but `erp.vuelosenglobos.mx` is not working online and shows as missed page, this are my global settings for my subdomain within Virtualmin:

[image]

What else can i do to fix this?